# Product of positive definite and negative definite commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two real-valued symmetric matrices $A, B$.Let $A$ be positive-definite and $B$ be negative-definite, and also let $AB = BA$.

Consider now the product, $C = AB$, which is guaranteed to be real since $A$ and $B$ are real, and it is also guaranteed to be symmetric since $[A,B] = 0$. Is $C$ negative-definite? Is there a simple proof of this fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Proof 1.* Note that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously unitarily diagonalisable.

*Proof 2.* Note that $A^{1/2}$ is a polynomial in $A$. Hence it commutes with $B$ and $AB=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hy, there is a theorem that says if two square complex matrices $A,B$ commute then there is $U$ unitary such that $U^*AU$ and $U^*BU$ are upper triangular. Here you have them hermitian so they are triangular and diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $C^*(A,B)$, the commutative $C^*$-subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ generated by $A$ and $B$.

By commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem, there exists a LCH space $X$ such that there is an isometric $*$-isomorphism
$$C^*(A,B) \cong C_0(X)$$
where positive elements correspond to nonnegative functions, and invertible elements correspond to invertible functions (which do not attain $0$).

Let $f_A > 0$ correspond to $A$ and  $f_B < 0$ correspond to $B$.
Then $f_Af_B < 0$ corresponds to $AB$ so $AB$ is negative definite.